# How to format array as key : value?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a array like this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Chat Show 
 [1] => Non-fiction 
 [2] => Inspirational
)
```

And i am trying to get this format:

```
     "genres": [
        {
            "name": "Chat Show"
        },
        {
            "name": "Non-fiction"
        },
        {
            "name": "Inspirational"
        }
   ]
```

but i get something like this:

```
genres": [
    "Chat Show",
    "Non-fiction",
    "Inspirational"
]
```

This is what i am doing:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Data))
{
 $Genres = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($row['genres'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

and then this is part of a bigger array

```
"genres" => $Genres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_r(
  json_encode(["genres" => array_map(
                              function($v) { return ['name' => $v]; },
                              $Genres)]));
```

result

```
{"genres":[{"name":"Chat Show"},{"name":"Non-fiction"},{"name":"Inspirational"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, here is your array in PHP

```
$var = array(
                "Chat Show",
                "Non-fiction" ,
                "Inspirational"
            );
```

Without a key "name". You should create a new array and push each element as an array to your new array.

```
$result = array();
foreach($var as $name)
{
    $arr = array("name"=>$name);
    array_push($result, $arr);
}
```

after that, encode your `$result` by using `json_encode`

```
$json = json_encode($result,true);
echo $json;
```

Here is my output by `echo $json`.

```
[{"name":"Chat Show"},{"name":"Non-fiction"},{"name":"Inspirational"}]
```

Comment: The two lines inside `foreach` can be written as `array_push($result, array("name"=>$name));` might save some processing power

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$Genres=array("Chat Show","Non-fiction","Non-fiction");
    $new["genres"]=array();
    foreach($Genres as $key => $name){
        $new["genres"][$key] = ['name' => $name];
    }
    echo json_encode($new);
```

**Output** 
`{"genres":[{"name":"Chat Show"},{"name":"Non-fiction"},{"name":"Non-fiction"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

The `json` string you posted here is not a valid json OR is part of `json`.

So, you might already have `genres` in your javascript, and want to get the remaining thing, which is

```
[  
    { "name": "Chat Show" },
    { "name": "Non-fiction" },
    { "name": "Inspirational" }
]
```

Your current PHP `$Genres` looks like this because you are exploding the string

```
$Genres = [ 'Chat Show', 'Non-fiction', 'Inspirational' ];
```

Apply this to change values of your current `$Genres`

```
array_walk($Genres, function(&$v){ $v = ['name'=>$v]; });
```

Use it in your javascript like,

```
"genres": <?php json_encode($Genres)?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
       `$genres_new['name']=$Genres;
echo json_encode($genres_new);`

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, that you have simple array of strings, but you want an associative multilevel array. This is an relative simple operation. First lets illustrate the problem with some code:

```
// That is what you have, an :
$Genres = [
    "Chat Show",
    "Non-fiction",
    "Inspirational",
];

// or the same for php > 5.4:
 $Genres = array(
    "Chat Show",
    "Non-fiction",
    "Inspirational",
);
```

This will produce the following json string (`echo json_encode($Genres);`):

```
 ["Chat Show","Non-fiction","Inspirational"]
```

But if you want such an output:

```
[{"name":"Chat Show"},{"name":"Non-fiction"},{"name":"Inspirational"}]
```

You have to convert the strings into an array. You can do that with that (or a similar loop):

```
foreach($Genres as $key => $name){
    $Genres[$key] = ['name' => $name];
}
```

After that your array look like this:

```
Array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Chat Show',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Non-fiction',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Inspirational',
  ),
)
```

Putting things together you will get something like that:

```
<?php

// Do whatever is necessary to build your Genres array ...
$Genres = [
    "Chat Show",
    "Non-fiction",
    "Inspirational",
];

// Convert the array into an array of arrays
foreach($Genres as $key => $name){
    $Genres[$key] = ['name' => $name];
}

echo json_encode($Genres);

/**
Now you will get this output:
[{"name":"Chat Show"},{"name":"Non-fiction"},{"name":"Inspirational"}]
*/

// After that you can add it to the bigger array:
$biggerArray = [];
$biggerArray['genres'] = $Genres;
echo json_encode($biggerArray);
/**
 Output:
 {"genres":[{"name":"Chat Show"},{"name":"Non-fiction"},{"name":"Inspirational"}]}
 */
```